# SQL get at least n elements before key in one query

Tags: sql, orientdb

Right now I have 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT login, permissions FROM User 
    WHERE login < ? 
    ORDER BY DESC login 
    LIMIT ? 
) ORDER BY login
```

And the second one:

```
SELECT login, permissions FROM User 
WHERE login >= ? 
ORDER BY login 
LIMIT ?
```

I want to get `n` results before key.

- First, I execute first query with limit `n`.
- Then I see how many results I received `results.count()`.
- Then I perform second query with remaining keys `let remaining = n - result.count()`, if it is needed (`remaining > 0`).

Is is possible to do this in one query?

Example:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d

get(key = 'a', limit = 2) would return a, b
get(key = 'c', limit = 2) would return a, b
get(key = 'd', limit = 2) would return b, c
get(key = 'd', limit = 3) would return a, b, c
```

Comment: first query doesnt have any fields selected or you miss the `*`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza fixed -> yeah I missed it, but in Orientdb this is valid query, so that's why I forgot about it. That explains permissions too -> in relational database that would be considered as not normalized.

Comment: You know `n` before hand? or is calculated by `result.count`?

Comment: n is a parameter, new per each request ( I'm trying to implement paging). See provided example.

Answer (score 2):

If you need paging you are asking the wrong question.

For your current question even when not familiar with orient db.

You need `UNION` both querys:

```
select * 
from table 
where login < ? 
order by login DESC
limit n

UNION ALL

select * 
from table 
where login >= ? 
order by login 
limit n             -- worst case scenerio all n logins are equal or beyound ?
```

THEN do a select over that subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( ... ) as union_query
ORDER BY login
limit n
```

Comment: This is exactly my 1st query, and it works if there is enough records before the key, and it don't fit my usecase completely. If there is for example 3 records before the key, and I wanted to receive 5 records, I will take those 2 remaining records after the key.

Comment: I didnt see that in your question. That is why a good example is need it.

Comment: check my editing. I put it separated because not sure how would be the sintaxis on orient. But you test first the union, then perfom a select over that subquery.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but would the engine optimize the number of records queried? With trivial implementation for limit = 2000 it would look for 4000 entries. Is it acceptable?

Comment: My short answer is **`Yes`**, with proper index that query should be trivial. But again I think you asked the wrong question. There are more efficient ways to do pagging. If you have a row_number and need page K you ask for `SELECT * FROM table WHERE row_id between n*K and n*(K+1)`. My suggesion is you google for `pagging in orientdb`

Comment: That's a good and simple solution. You'll probably need parentheses: `(select ... limit n) union all (select ... limit n)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is ranking your records: You prefer records before the key. So records from the key on are considered second best. Then you only want a certain amount of rows as close to the key as possible. A possible ranking would be the row numbers according to the key, but multiplied with -1 for keys before the given one. E.g. when looking for key `d`:

```
key  rn
a    -1
b    -2
c    -3
d    +4
e    +5
```

ordered by rank:

```
key  rn
c    -3
b    -2
a    -1
d    +4
e    +5
```

So you'd get c first, then b, then a, then d, then e.

I don't know OrientDB, so here is standard SQL:

```
select login, permissions
from
(
  select 
    login, 
    permissions, 
    case when login < :value then
      -row_number() over (order by login)
    else
      row_number() over (order by login)
    end as rn
  from user
)
order by rn
fetch first :n rows only;
```

Comment: This probably work, but that requiere a full scan of the table, so not very efficient if very large tables. Also you still need order by login at the end, OP want a pagging function, so `a` is should be first, not `c`